# Pipenv having trouble installing despite Python being installed

Tags: python, pipenv

After installing Python, I am now trying to install the pipenv dependency by running this command in the terminal `python 3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip pipenv`. However, after attempting to execute the command, I receive this error **zsh: command not found: python**. I find it odd because Python is definitely installed. I've tried uninstalling then reinstalling the app, but I've had no success.

Comment: Try 'python3' instead of 'python'.

Comment: @amd This seems to have solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using command to run the environment `python3 ...`